# Thumb control highlighted and dragging appearance

Tags: c#, windows-runtime

I'm using a thumb control in a windows store app to represent a draggable image.  However whenever I hover over it it changes into a grey box, and when I drag it it turns into a darker grey box.  When release it reverts to the image I gave it as a background.  Is there any way to turn off or customize away the highlight/focus and dragging appearances?

**EDIT:**

Here is my XAML for the control.  I have it inside a grid but don't do anything with that.

```
<Canvas x:Name="PART_background" Background="White" Height="140" Width="20">
    <Thumb x:Name="PART_drag" Canvas.Left="0" Width="20" Height="50">
        <Thumb.BorderBrush>
            <SolidColorBrush Color="Black" Opacity="0"></SolidColorBrush>
        </Thumb.BorderBrush>

        <Thumb.Background>
            <ImageBrush x:Name="PART_image" Stretch="None" AlignmentX="Center" />
        </Thumb.Background>
    </Thumb>
</Canvas>
```

Comment: Post your current XAML.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to edit the template - it works best in Blend, then change the visual state animations. The default template has a few `Border` elements and for various visual states (PointerPressed, PointerOver) - it animates Opacity of these borders. Here's the extracted template. You can simply remove the Storyboards to get rid of the visual feedback.

```
<Page
    x:Class="App132.MainPage"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="using:App132"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    mc:Ignorable="d">
    <Page.Resources>
        <Style x:Key="ThumbStyle1" TargetType="Thumb">
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource ThumbBackgroundThemeBrush}"/>
            <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="1"/>
            <Setter Property="IsTabStop" Value="False"/>
            <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="{StaticResource ThumbBorderThemeBrush}"/>
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="Thumb">
                        <Grid>
                            <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                                <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                                    <VisualState x:Name="Normal"/>
                                    <VisualState x:Name="PointerOver">
                                        <Storyboard>
                                            <DoubleAnimation Duration="0" To="1" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" Storyboard.TargetName="BackgroundPointerOver"/>
                                            <DoubleAnimation Duration="0" To="0" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" Storyboard.TargetName="Background"/>
                                        </Storyboard>
                                    </VisualState>
                                    <VisualState x:Name="Pressed">
                                        <Storyboard>
                                            <DoubleAnimation Duration="0" To="1" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" Storyboard.TargetName="BackgroundPressed"/>
                                            <DoubleAnimation Duration="0" To="0" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" Storyboard.TargetName="Background"/>
                                        </Storyboard>
                                    </VisualState>
                                    <VisualState x:Name="Disabled"/>
                                </VisualStateGroup>
                                <VisualStateGroup x:Name="FocusStates">
                                    <VisualState x:Name="Unfocused"/>
                                    <VisualState x:Name="Focused"/>
                                </VisualStateGroup>
                            </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                            <Border x:Name="Background" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"/>
                            <Border x:Name="BackgroundPointerOver" BorderBrush="{StaticResource ThumbPointerOverBorderThemeBrush}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" Background="{StaticResource ThumbPointerOverBackgroundThemeBrush}" Opacity="0"/>
                            <Border x:Name="BackgroundPressed" BorderBrush="{StaticResource ThumbPressedBorderThemeBrush}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" Background="{StaticResource ThumbPressedBackgroundThemeBrush}" Opacity="0"/>
                        </Grid>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
    </Page.Resources>

    <Grid Background="{StaticResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
        <Thumb HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="270" Margin="170,230,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="390" Style="{StaticResource ThumbStyle1}"/>
    </Grid>
</Page>
```

Comment: I inlined the style on the thumb control using this a template and it worked perfectly!